# Linq query serializaton (WPF, C#, XmlSerializer)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm want to serialize my query. I did:

```
 MyDBViewDataContext db = new MyDBViewDataContext();
 List<test_view> tvq = (from tt in db.test_views
                       select tt).ToList();

 const string filename = "serial_file.xml";

 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(test_view));
 FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Create);

 serializer.Serialize(stream, tvq);
 stream.Close();
```

But something is wrong, as I got error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line code

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(test_view));
```

to

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<test_view>));
```

Comment: thank you **TriV**!. Just tested and it's working :)